# Conditional condition in ON clause

Tags: mysql, yii2

I am trying to apply a conditional condition inside ON clause of a LEFT JOIN. What I am trying to achieve is somewhat like this:

**Pseudo Code**

```
SELECT * FROM item AS i
LEFT JOIN sales AS s ON i.sku = s.item_no
AND (some condition)
AND (
  IF (s.type = 0 AND s.code = 'me')
  ELSEIF (s.type = 1 AND s.code = 'my-group')
  ELSEIF (s.type = 2)
)
```

I want the query to return the row, if it matches any one of the conditions (Edit: and if it matches one, should omit the rest for the same item).

**Sample Data**

Sales

```
item_no | type | code     | price
1         0      me         10
1         1      my-group   12
1         2                 14
2         1      my-group   20
2         2                 22
3         2                 30
4         0      not-me     40
```

I want the query to return

```
item_no | type | code     | price
1         0      me         10
2         1      my-group   20
3         2                 30
```

Edit: The sales is table is used to apply special prices for individual users, user groups, and/or all users.
if type = 0, code contains username. (for a single user)
if type = 1, code contains user-group. (for users in a group)
if type = 2, code contains empty-string (for all users).

Comment: I don't get it, why don't you use OR instead of ELSEIF ?
AND (
  (s.type = 0 AND s.code = 'me')
  OR (s.type = 1 AND s.code = 'my-group')
  OR (s.type = 2)
)

Comment: When I check your query, the expected result should also include records with `item_no` `1` and `type`  `1`, `item_no` `1` and `type` `2`, `item_no` `2` and `type` `1`. These records are not in your expected result. May I know the reason for that?

Comment: @sab using OR will return all results and I don't want that.

Comment: @Viki888 question edited. Kindly check it.

Comment: @musafar006 Can you also provide sample data from `item` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following SQL (assumed, the the table sales has a unique id field as usual in yii):

```
SELECT * FROM item AS i
LEFT JOIN sales AS s ON i.sku = s.item_no
AND id = (
  SELECT id FROM sales
  WHERE item_no = i.sku
  AND (type = 0 AND code = 'me' OR
       type = 1 AND code = 'my-group' OR
       type = 2)
  ORDER BY type
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following -

```
SELECT *,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(s.type ORDER BY  s.type),','1) AS `type`,    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(s.code ORDER BY  s.type),','1) AS `code`,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(s.price ORDER BY  s.type),','1) AS `price` 
FROM item AS i 
LEFT JOIN sales AS s 
ON i.sku = s.item_no AND (SOME CONDITION)
GROUP BY i.sku
```